# Unknown email on login page Facebook

Tags: facebook, login

I was using Facebook on Opera when I needed to clear the cache history.
I then shut down the laptop and went to do something else.

When I came back, I launched Opera (which opened the latest page I was on before shutting down the laptop).

On the Facebook login page this email address appeared:

> 1580979448583207_xdzdsmbm@tfbworknw.net

It was just pre-written in the email field. There's no record of it in the field history. Also no password was set.

I'm the only one using this laptop. Ever.

If that was a random e-mail address, I would consider being hacked (for whatever reason), but this address?

It seems the domain name is from Facebook, but almost no trace of it on Google.

> 13 apr. 2015 - Tfbworknw.net is hosted in , , and is owned by Domain Administrator (Facebook, Inc.). Tfbworknw.net was created on 2015-04-13 and changed ...

What is it? And more important, where does it come from?

Any reason to be worried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to do your usage of Facebook Workplace prior to login in to personal Facebook. The auto-populated e-mail 1580979448583207_xdzdsmbm@tfbworknw.net was the cache from Facebook Workplace.